# Android: How can I open a dialog which is started while sleep?

Tags: android, timer, dialog, wakeup

In my app I have a service which has a BroadcastReceiver which listens to TIME_TICK.
I already could check if a date is reached. So if for excemple the 04.01.2011 11:00 pm is reached there is a vibration alarm.
But how could I open a dialog so that after I unlocked my screen it is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch an intent for an activity when the time is reached.

Declare on the manifest a theme for this activity like:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

and create a view for the activity just like the inside of a dialog, so you don't need to create an AlertDialog.

Comment: I don't think you can open a dialog without an activity. Since you are on a BroadcastReceiver you're not on an activity.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. I have this service with the BroadcastReceiver which has an Intentfilter with action.TIME_TICK. If now the time is reached I call vibrator 3000 ms and after that an intent to an activity. In this activty is the only thing in the onCreate method that it starts an alert dialoge, but the only thing that happens is, that the vibration alarm is shorter and if I unlock my screen there is nothing.

Comment: Sorry, by DialogActivity I meant to say to create an Activity and have on the manifest the theme andoid:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog", then you create a view with the text and buttons and use as the activity view. Android will then show your activity like an dialog and you don't need to have to create an AlertDialog.